# Passing value of pig variable from one action to another action in Oozie

Tags: apache-pig, oozie

My oozie workflow snippet looks like:

```
<workflow-app name="Abandonment_Workflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="pig-0581"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="pig-0581">
        <pig>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <script>/user/793972/TRM/1.pig</script>
              <param>input=/data/*/*.bz2</param>
            <archive>/user/a.jar#a.jar</archive>
        </pig>
        <ok to="fork-3d77"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <action name="pig-a915">
        <pig>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <script>/user/793972/TRM/2.pig</script>
              <param>input=/data/*/*.bz2</param>
            <archive>/user/a.jar#a.jar</archive>
            </pig>
            <ok to="join-31be"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
     .......
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

In pig script 1.pig

```
data = LOAD $input USING PigStorage('\t') AS 
(timestamp:chararray,server:chararray,sessionid:chararray);
```

In pig script 2.pig, I want to use the variable -'data' in 1.pig ,

cleandata = foreach data generate .....

Is it possible to do so.

If yes,then please suggest how

Comment: Am not sure exact requirement of Using the Data from pig1.pig script to pig2.pig script, as you can combined the same single Pig script it self, as You are calling both the pig script action from one after one. 
as in both the case the Dump will be loaded in Temp location.

Comment: Correct Debjit. Sorry for the confusion.I haven't posted the whole of the oozie workflow.
My intention is to run 3 pig script in parallel, using the first pig script's value.
Hence the Question

Comment: No, i don't think that is possible

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot achieve this in pig. When pig scripts are executed, compiler will convert pig latin commands into one or more MR jobs and these will be running independently. So two pig scripts cannot communicate each other.

However, there is something you can try is Pig macros.

```
--LoadInput.macro
DEFINE loadInput(input) returns data{
$data = LOAD '$input' USING PigStorage('\t') AS 
       (timestamp:chararray,server:chararray,sessionid:chararray);
}
```

Pig Script 1

```
IMPORT '/path/LoadInput.macro';
data = loadInput($input);
cleandata = FOREACH data GENERATE timestamp, sessionid;
```

Pig Script 2

```
IMPORT '/path/LoadInput.macro';
data2 = loadInput($input);
cleandata2 = FOREACH data2 GENERATE timestamp, server;
```